# Mpdf no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

Estou usando a biblioteca `Mpdf` no meu projeto. Instalei via `Composer` e localmente com `php` versão 7.1 (O `php` do servidor em produção é 7.2) e está habilitado o *composer_autoload* do `CodeIgniter`. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente no ambiente local, mas ao subir o projeto 
em produção, dá erro dizendo que a *"class Mpdf não foi encontrada"*:

> Message: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

O que pode estar acontecendo? Por que localmente o sistema encontra a `class` e em produção não?.

Comment: já rodou composer dump-autoload no servidor de produção?

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto não e sinceramente nem sei como fazer, vou pesquisar como fazer ou teria algum link de tutorial para me enviar? E não vai dar problema com esse comando em  outras features que usa bibliotecas instaladas via composer?

Comment: Você instalou o mpdf pelo composer?

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto sim, instalei localmente via composer e quando subi para produção apresenta aquele erro

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e acrescente informações [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Mostre como está carregando a classe para a aplicação. Diga as versões das bibliotecas que está usando. Qual é a diferença entre o ambiente local e o de produção? SO?

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, anoto que o item de configuração `$config['composer_autoload']` setado para `TRUE` só vai carregar as bibliotecas que estiverem dentro de `application/vendor`. Isso implica, minimamente, que exista um `composer.json` dentro da pasta da aplicação. Se você instalou a `mPDF` em outro local, ela simplesmente não vai carregar. Em segundo lugar, uma biblioteca de terceiros deve ser declarada para poder ser instanciada na aplicação.

Pra iniciar, declare o local onde instalou a `mPDF`. Essa é a parte mais delicada, pois aqui você terá que indicar **exatamente** onde salvou o *vendor* da `mPDF`. O exemplo abaixo é num ambiente `Linux`, mas serve para qualquer sistema operacional. Eu adicionei o seguinte no final de `application/config/constants.php`:

```
defined('MPDF') or define('MPDF', "/usr/share/php/mpdf/mpdf-7.1.9/vendor/autoload.php");
```

Feito isso, salve a declaração da biblioteca no arquivo `application/libraries/Mpdf.php`:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mpdf {

    public $method;

    function __construct() {
        require_once MPDF;
        $this->method = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    }

}
```

Carregue a biblioteca declarada com [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload#auto-loading-resources) em `application/config/autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'mpdf'
);
```

Exemplo de uso num *method* de um *controller*:

```
function export() {
    $filename = 'sample.pdf';
    $html = '<html><body><p>Put some html here!</p></body></html>';
    $this->mpdf->method->SetTitle($filename);
    $this->mpdf->method->SetAuthor('Author name here');
    $this->mpdf->method->SetCreator('Creator name here');
    $this->mpdf->method->SetSubject('Testing mPDF create functionality on this system');
    $this->mpdf->method->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->mpdf->method->Output($filename, 'D');
}
```

Pronto, cada coisa em seu lugar, não tem como dar errado. Fazendo dessa forma, não importa em que ambiente você publicar o código, vai funcionar.

**OBS:** qualquer biblioteca `PHP` pode ser carregada dessa maneira para um sistema feito com `CodeIgniter` [v3.1.10](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html#version-3-1-10).

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta bem explicada! Não foi eu quem pediu ajuda, mas tive as mesmas dificuldades com o mPdf e sua resposta foi perfeita para resolver o meu problema.